# After migrating my code from Bit bucket to Git hub , code was not found

Tags: github

I have migrated my code from bit bucket to Git hub and i got successfully completed message too but i am not able to find the code in Git hub

Tried all options which supposed to do.
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <GitHub_repo_address>

Anyone faced the same issue please update here.

Comment: Have you tried just going to github.com and logging in and clicking on your avatar in the top right and choosing "Your Repositories" and looking to see if it is even in the list?

Answer (score 0):

can you share more details about the project . is your migrated project in zipped form?
have your downloaded it or your project is still on cloud .
if you have have downloaded the project then in order to add it to Github repo

do following steps

Steps to Upload a Project:

1. Initialize a Git Repository:
   Open GitHub Desktop.
   Click on "File" in the menu, then select "Add Local Repository."
   Choose the local directory where your project is located and click "Add Repository."
2. Commit Changes:
   In GitHub Desktop, you will see the changes made to your project files.
   Write a summary and a detailed description of the changes.
   Click on "Commit to main" (or the name of your main branch).
3. Publish the Repository to GitHub:
   After committing changes, click on the "Repository" menu and select "Push to origin" (or the name of your remote repository).
   This action will upload your changes to GitHub.
4. Verify on GitHub:
   Open your web browser and go to your GitHub account.
   Navigate to the repository to confirm that your project has been uploaded.
   That's it! Your project should now be available on GitHub.

Additional Tips:
Branches:

If you are working on branches other than the main branch, make sure to switch to the branch you want to push before committing and pushing.
.gitignore:

Create a .gitignore file in your project directory to specify which files or directories should be ignored by Git. For example, you might want to ignore files generated by your IDE, compiled binaries, or sensitive information like API keys.
README.md:

Consider creating a README.md file in your repository to provide information about your project, instructions for other developers, or any necessary documentation.
This should cover the basic process of uploading a project to GitHub using GitHub Desktop. If you encounter any issues, refer to GitHub's documentation or community forums for assistance.